# Помогите решить проблему с отображением шрифтов в Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, шрифты

У клиентов нашего сервиса был замечен баг, при котором не отображается ни один шрифт на сайте. Шрифт подгружается с нашего сервера (форматы woff, ttf, eot, svg), шрифт Lato Sans. В самих стилях указано, что в случае недоступности шрифта, надо использовать Arial, либо любой другой системный шрифт без засечек. Так же в стилях указано сглаживание шрифта, вот отрывок из кода:

```css
font-family: "Lato Sans", "PT Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
font-smooth: always;
text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
```

Пример загрузки одного из типа шрифта:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato Sans';
    src: url('/Content/webfonts/LatoSans/lato-regular.eot');
    src: url('/Content/webfonts/LatoSans/lato-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/Content/webfonts/LatoSans/lato-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/Content/webfonts/LatoSans/lato-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Описание проблемы: Клиент заходит на сайт (Google Chrome 58, Windows), но не видит никакого текста. То есть вся графика отрендерилась, а шрифт нет. Причем текст системным шрифтом тоже не показывается. И после изменения размера браузера шрифт как будто догружается, и все отображается. Проблема пока замечена только в одном браузере, в остальных на базе WebKit/Blink тоже возможна.

[image: Пример того, как это выглядит у клиента]

Самому повторить получилось только один раз, после перезагрузки страницы уже все стало нормально, соответственно баг отловить и пофиксить уже не смог. В чем может быть проблема, и как ее решить?

Применил несколько решений, которые нагуглил, но не помогли - это загружать шрифт после загрузки основной страницы, через JavaScript, по событию onLoad. И делать анимацию в 1ms после загрузки страницы, что бы браузер перерендерил шрифт (ниже пример последнего фикса).

```css
body {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

За хромом біла замечена особенность что если за неким шрифтом браузер повторно обращается, то что-то такое у меня тоже вылезло на Angulare 4. Я по неосторожности проинклудил файл подключения шрифтов в несколько компонентов, в следствии чего ангуляр повторно обращался на сервер за этим шрифтом. Как результат, после повторной подгрузки (а это был на самом деле код 302) шрифт как будто выводился белым. Если в дебагере покликать флажок color он появлялся. Проследить за этим довольно просто. Понаблюдайте в консоле во вкладке network

Comment: Проверил, шрифт подключается только один раз для каждого начертания, везде 200 код.